# Function pointers and callbacks

Tags: c++, function, pointers, callback

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and the OpenCV 2.3.0 libraries to write up an application for image processing.

I have a piece of code that is erroneous for me and I am not sure how to fix it. I am implementing an application where there will be 2 or 3 windows open at the same time and I want each one of them to be assigned with a different **CvMouseCallback** function. I want all these **CvMouseCallback** functions to be in a different class together with another function that returns a pointer to one of these functions according to what the user selects.

My **Window.h** contains this piece of code.

```
class Window
{
public:
   ... // constructors and destructors
   void setMouseHandler( CvMouseCallback mouseHandler );
private:
   ... // other stuff
};
```

and **Window.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void Window::setMouseHandler( CvMouseCallback mouseHandler )
{
    cvSetMouseCallback( win, mouseHandler, NULL );
}
```

Now, the **MouseHandler.h** file

```
class MouseHandler
{
public:
   ...
   CvMouseCallback selectHandler( int option );
   void __cdecl selectROI( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param );

private:
   Image *in;
   Window *win;
   void ( CV_CDECL MouseHandler::*callback )( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param );
};
```

and lastly, in **MouseHandler.cpp** I contain

```
void __cdecl MouseHandler::selectROI( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param )
{
   //do something
}

CvMouseCallback MouseHandler::selectHandler( int option )
{
   callback = (MouseHandler::selectROI);
   return callback;
}
```

The last bit of information you might need is the definition of CvMouseCallback from the OpenCV library which is

```
typedef void (CV_CDECL *CvMouseCallback )(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param);
```

Now, the question is: When I return the callback from the last function in MouseHandler.cpp it is underlined with an error saying:

> Error: return value type does not match the function type.

I know what it says is that I am trying to impose to that function to return something that does not look like the object it is being asking for. However, it's just a function and if I could do that in the main class it would be ok. My problem is how can selectHandler return a pointer to the selectROI function so that it can be used by another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use a `static` function here:

```
static void __cdecl selectROI( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param );
```

and

```
void ( CV_CDECL *callback )( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param );
```

accordingly.

The thing is that this definition:

```
typedef void (CV_CDECL *CvMouseCallback )(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param);
```

Is not a class member function, while yours is a member of class `MouseHandler`, which means its a different signature and different parameter list (to accommodate for `this`). Using `static` class member function solves it for you.

You'll have to figure out how to pass the object context data to the `static` function of course.

Comment: thank, but I have already tried a static function but callback returns another error

>  Error: expression must be a modifiable value

and the return error is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your `selectROI()` method, since it is not static, requires an implicit `this` parameter as its first argument.  If you try making it static, you will have a better chance at getting it working, though really if you are passing it to a C API as you are, you technically need to pass an `extern "C"` function pointer for everything to be fully proper and portable.  That might be a trivial forwarding function like this:

```
extern "C" void selectROI( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param );
```

Then, if you want your C++ class method to not be static (so it can access class member variables), you just need to pass a pointer to a MouseHandler object as the third argument to `cvSetMouseCallback()` and you will then receive the same in your callback, which can then look like this:

```
extern "C" void selectROI( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param )
{
    static_cast<MouseHandler*>(param)->selectROI( event, x, y, flags);
}
```

Comment: I've done that, but how can I return the function pointer from the selectHandler function?

Comment: return selectROI; will return a pointer to the extern "C" function which will suffice.  Whoever calls selectHandler() to get the handler will need to know that they should pass its result together with the address of a MouseHandler object though.  You might consider having a function to tell MouseHandler to register itself instead.

Comment: selectHandler method still cannot return selectROI, since it still expects a CvMouseCallback, which is actually just a pointer to a function. What's the purpose of the static_cast? How should I use it in the selectRoi function? like on top and then whatever happens in that function should be below? thanks

Comment: The selectROI function is just a thin wrapper using the C calling convention so as to be suitable for passing to the C API you are using.  All it does is cast the "param" pointer to your class type (you know this cast will be OK if you always pass a pointer to your class to the callback registration C function).  You then write your code in your (non-static) class method as before.  In other words, my selectROI() function there is the complete thing--you don't need to add anything in its body.

Comment: I cannot say I fully understand what you are trying to say, but I do get most of it. I want my selectROI function to do have some extra functionality and I want this member function to be passed to cvSetMouseCallback, which is in Main.cpp as a CvMouseCallback function. static_cast is a pointer-to-class type conversion. I only want to know if there's any possibility to convert the class member function selectROI to a CvMouseCallback and return it back to main or return MouseHandler::selectROI function to Main and then convert it to CvMouseCallback. CvMouseCallback is a typedef in highgui_c.h

Comment: No you cannot "convert" (by casting or otherwise) a C++ class member function to a C function pointer.  This is exactly why you need the wrapper function that does the casting of your class instance from void*--because while you can stash a C++ object pointer inside a C void*, you cannot stash a C++ function pointer (technically not even static class methods, but especially not non-static ones) inside a C function pointer.